# File uploading in struts 2 yields files with .tmp extensions

Tags: java, file

This is what I have so far. I know the file works because when I force the .jpg extension and upload a .jpg image it works fine. But the filename looks like this with the appended .jpg.

> E:\Documents and Settings\mgrif002\Desktop\data\upload_59fef24e_1302d1a3fb9__7ff5_00000001.tmp.jpg

```
try 
{
    String filePath = "E:/Documents and Settings/mgrif002/Desktop/data/";
    //System.out.println("Server path:" + filePath);
    System.out.println(form.getFile().getAbsolutePath());
    File fileToCreate = new File(filePath,form.getFile().getAbsolutePath()+".jpg");

    FileUtils.copyFile(form.getFile(), fileToCreate);

    Dicom dicom_file = new Dicom(pid,fileToCreate.getAbsolutePath(), form.getName(),true,((short)1));
    ccr.saveDicom(dicom_file);
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `.tmp` by `.jpg` instead of appending `.jpg`. There are several ways, such as [substringing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) the part until the [last](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29) period, or [regex](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) replacing the last `.tmp` part, etc.

```
String fileName = form.getFile().getName().replaceAll("\\.tmp$", ".jpg");
File fileToCreate = new File(filePath, fileName);
// ...
```

Comment: Wow that is ridiculously simple. Thanks!

Comment: As an aside comment, the issue with this is that there is no validation regarding the content of the file, it could be a malicious `exe` file, uploaded as a `tmp`  and renamed as a `jpg`. So whoever is using this solution, make sure you are validating the content of the file, using perhaps `Apache Tika`.

Answer (score 3):

this was killing me as well.  This is how I solved the issue.  Thought this might save someone a few precious ours of their lives :)

```
if (request instanceof MultiPartRequestWrapper) {
                MultiPartRequestWrapper multiWrapper =
                    (MultiPartRequestWrapper) request;
                if (multiWrapper != null) {
                    HttpServletRequest hrequest = (HttpServletRequest)request;

                    Enumeration fileParameterNames = multiWrapper.getFileParameterNames();              
                    //String fileName = multiWrapper.getFileNames("upload")[0];
                    if(fileParameterNames.hasMoreElements()){
                        String inputValue = (String) fileParameterNames.nextElement();
                        String[] localFileNames = multiWrapper.getFileNames(inputValue);
                        for (String fn : localFileNames) {
                            System.out.println("local filename = " + fn);                   
                        }
                        File[] files = multiWrapper.getFiles(inputValue);
                        HttpSession ses = hrequest.getSession();
                        User user = (User) ses.getAttribute("user");
                        IR loggedInIR = user.getIr();

                        for (File cf : files) {
                            File destFile = new File(cf.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath()+"\\"+loggedInIR.getId()+"\\images\\"+localFileNames[0]);
                            FileUtils.copyFile(cf, destFile);
                            FileUtils.deleteQuietly(cf);

                        }               
                    }
                }
            }
```